# spring cloud stream kinesis configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I am trying integrate spring cloud stream kinesis in my app but i cant find all configuration option in there manual. I have seen this link:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc

There are few properties mentioned like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount=
```

I would like to know how can i set some of the properties which i cant see in the documentation:

```
hostname
port number
access key
secret key
username
```

I am looking for something like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.binder.host=
spring.cloud.stream.binder.port=
spring.cloud.stream.binder.access_key=
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `host` or `port` for AWS services. You only do a connection to the AWS via an auto-configuration. The Spring Cloud Kinesis Binder is fully based on the auto-configuration provided by the Spring Cloud AWS project. So, you need to follow its documentation how to configure `accessKey` and `secretKey`: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-aws.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration:

> cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey
>
> cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey

You also may consider to use a `cloud.aws.region.static` if you don't run your application in the EC2 environment.

There is no more magic than standard AWS connection settings and auto-configuration provided by the Spring Cloud AWS.

Or you can rely on the standard AWS credentials file instead.